# Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: ["eq", "$x-amz-storage-class", "STANDARD_IA"]

Tags: amazon-s3, policy, storage-class-specifier

I am trying to specify the storage class for an AWS S3 object (image file) on its upload from a web page post.  All works fine without the storage class specification but when I add it to the policy the page redirects to an error page with XML that indicates:

```
Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: ["eq", "$x-amz-storage-class", "STANDARD_IA"]
```

I've tried different values for the storage class such as upper/lower case, STANDARD, STANDARD-IA, etc but nothing seems to work.  Any help would be appreciated.

This is the object policy before its encoded:

```
{
    "expiration": "2040-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "conditions": [ 
        {"bucket": "dev-image"},
        ["starts-with", "$key", ""],
        {"acl": "private"},
        {"success_action_redirect": "http://localhost/Image.jsp"},
        ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""],
        {"x-amz-storage-class": "STANDARD_IA"},              <<<<< Causes Problem
        ["content-length-range", 0, 10485760]
    ]
}
```

Comment: The field has to be added both the the form and the policy. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64975612/aws-s3-post-object-rejects-extra-form-fields).

Answer (score 0):

The error message is indicating the form fields do not match the policy conditions.  The policy conditions must be a 1:1 match with the form fields; they must match in name and value.  Adding an input field "x-amz-storage-class" with value "STANDARD_IA" to the form fixes the error.